# Qt Quick bindings not updated at startup

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Trying to make a very simple node editor in Qt Quick.

The most tricky part seems to be the `Connection` item, which has to track the two *absolute* positions of the source and destination `IOPort`s.

The following code works fine, except that the bindings are not evaluated (or are evaluated in the wrong order) at startup, resulting in the connection line to be in the wrong position at startup:

[image]

which is then adjusted to the correct position as soon as either node is moved:

[image]

I thought about adding:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    start = mapFromItem(from, 0, 0)
    end = mapFromItem(to, 0, 0)
}
```

to `Connection`, which fixes the startup problem, but breaks the bindings.

So I resorted to this ugly hack:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    from.x = from.x+1
    from.x = from.x-1
}
```

Is there a better solution to this problem?

(files available in GitHub repository, link at bottom)

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 420
    height: 280
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Node editor")

    Node {
        x: 20
        y: 40
        width: 120
        height: 50

        IOPort {id: o1; x: 0; y: parent.height}
    }

    Node {
        x: 260
        y: 140
        width: 120
        height: 50

        IOPort {id: i1; x: 0; y: 0}
    }

    Connection {
        from: o1; to: i1
    }
}
```

Node.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    border.color: "black"
    border.width: 2
    color: "#eee"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: rect
    }
}
```

IOPort.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: root
    property real size: 15
    property real globalX: x + parent.x
    property real globalY: y + parent.y
    property real globalZ: 1 + parent.z

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        x: -width/2
        y: -height/2
        width: root.size
        height: root.size
        border.color: "black"
        color: "gray"
    }
}
```

Connection.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.15

Shape {
    id: root
    property IOPort from
    property IOPort to
    x: Math.min(from.globalX, to.globalX)
    y: Math.min(from.globalY, to.globalY)
    z: Math.max(from.globalZ, to.globalZ) + 0.5
    width: Math.abs(from.globalX - to.globalX)
    height: Math.abs(from.globalY - to.globalY)
    property point start: from.globalX, from.globalY, to.globalX, to.globalY, mapFromItem(from, 0, 0)
    property point end: from.globalX, from.globalY, to.globalX, to.globalY, mapFromItem(to, 0, 0)

    ShapePath {
        strokeWidth: 4
        strokeColor: "black"
        startX: root.start.x
        startY: root.start.y
        PathLine {
            x: root.end.x
            y: root.end.y
        }
    }
}
```

GitHub repository: [https://github.com/fferri/qtquick-simple-node-editor.git](https://github.com/fferri/qtquick-simple-node-editor/tree/947fb1be0e7bdd19c90eba51db429f5418e021d7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot currently reproduce the error but I think I found a problem:

Your `Connection` `root`'s `start` and `end` properties are missing a "forced" dependency on that same object's `x` and `y`

For some reason you decided to not only to set the coordinates for path's points but also move the whole `Connection` element itself. So if `root`'s `x` and `y` happen to update after `start` and `end` did, the latter still contain relative coordinates of the point when `x` and `y` were still default (probably `0,0`) and thus the line becomes displaced by `x,y` pixels.

Try changing them this way (I also removed dependencies you shouldn't need):

```
property point start: from.globalX, from.globalY, x, y, mapFromItem(from, 0, 0)
property point end: x, y, to.globalX, to.globalY, mapFromItem(to, 0, 0)
```

*(There were more suggestions here in case this didn't work but they were removed because the above seems to have solved the issue)*

Comment: You're totally right: `Connection`'s `start` and `end` properties are missing the dependency on `Connection`'s `x` and `y`. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Maybe it is not necessary for the `ShapePath` to be (visually) contained in its parent (`Shape`) rectangle, but I thought it would make more sense in the future development, e.g. if I need to make the connection clickable.

Comment: You would still need to make a `MouseArea` that could be in any position.. but I guess I get where you are coming from. If this solved your problem completely, please accept the answer so that your question is marked as not needing any more answers. Thanks.